# Sails.JS partial load issue from the "assets" folder

Tags: node.js, angular, sails.js

I'm using Sails.JS as the backend with Angular 6 as the frontend. In my application's homepage.ejs, I need to load HTML from the assets folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <!-- webpack generate html -->
 <%- partial('../assets/dist/index.html') %>

</html>
```

However, I get an error when accessing http://localhost:1337/:

**F:\development\SchoolERP\views\pages\homepage.ejs:5 3| 4| >> 5| <%- partial('../assets/dist/index.html') %> 6| 7| Could not find partial ../assets/dist/index.html at Object.partial (F:\development\SchoolERP\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\views\default-view-rendering-fn.js:305:11)**

Yet, my Angular 6 URL runs fine at http://localhost:4200.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too, [In Sails documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets) sais when you lift your app, the content of assets dir will be moved to *.tmp/public*, it means that your angular scripts after get builded will be available in *http://localhost:1337/dist/index.html*,  having this in mind I solved this following these steps:

1. Modified homepage.ejs as follows:

   ```
    // Ichange this line:
    <%- partial('../assets/dist/index.html') %>
    // for this one:
    <%- include ../../.tmp/public/dist/index.html %>
    // You just have to add the relative path for index.html
    // generated when you lift sails
   ```
2. I uncommented the following lines in config/http.js:

   ```
   order: [
    'cookieParser',
    'session',
    'bodyParser',
    'compress',
    // 'poweredBy',
    'router',
    'www',
    'favicon',
   ],
   ```
3. Tell angular where to find his scripts, so build your ng-app whit this command:

   ```
   $ ng build --base-href /dist/
   ```
4. Now lift your app and angular will be in http://localhost:1337/

Hope this helps you!